# Artifactory - Manage external dependencies

Tags: artifactory

I'm wondering how other Artifactory Admins do that so here's my question:

We're starting to use Artifactory to manage our artifacts. Internal as well as external artifacts. The external artifacts are all available in an internal repository. This is so because of a conversion from a file based repository to Artifactory.

Now this is starting to cause issues and I'm wondering how others are managing the external dependencies? As an Artifactory Administrator I want to be sure that my developers only use artifacts which have the correct license so I don't want to have a "feel free to download everything from the internet" culture.

I want to provide some sort of a "whitelisted and approved" set of external Artifacts.

Is this possible using Artifactory OSS or do we manually download the artifacts from a remote repository and deploy it to our local repository?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done with writing a [user plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins) but it will require a PRO version of Artifactory. You can see [here](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/governance) examples to a governance control plugin that was written in the past.

With OSS version you can't reject downloads of users based on license.

Hope that answer your question.

Comment: Hm... yes after the research I did I was afraid that this is the only solution. Thank you!